# Pushing deleted git tag to remote repository - branch permission error

Tags: git

I incorrectly tagged a branch that was merged to a remote repository, and I want to delete it.  So I created a clean directory, cloned the repository, and deleted the tag:

```
git tag -d TAG_NAME COMMIT_HASH
```

That worked no problem.  I then tried to push to the remote repository using this command I found in a similar question on here:

```
git push origin :refs/tags/TAG_NAME
```

I got the error: The branch refs/tags/int/TAG_NAME is protected by branch permissions.  It cannot be deleted.  Check your branch permissions configuration with the project administrator.

There is a branch with the same name as TAG_NAME.  Would this be causing the issue?  Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Have you deleted the tag from remote or just only in your local master?

Comment: I deleted the tag in my local cloned repo, and am trying to push it to a remote repo.

Comment: In your case, you don't have permission to delete the tag from the remote origin. Error log says clearly, you need to check with your admin. Is not due to branch with the same tag.